# Xerox Docuprint P12 drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I can't seem to find any drivers past Windows NT for this printer. I was wondering if anyone knew how to install it on Windows 7. I wouldn't mind using other drivers or some type of 'hack-around'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no windows 7 drivers for this printer.

There is a workaround which you can try otherwise buy a new printer:
Someone claims that he was able to install his P12 on windows 7 64 bit with the HP LaserJet III Drivers and it seems to be working fine.The test sheet sees the printer as a HP LaserJet III but you can name the printer Xerox P12 during the install.

select printers and hardware in the windows 7 menu.

Add a printer[image]

select Xerox DocuPrint P12.

When it is asking for driver: Select HP LaserJet III and let it do an update of the drivers.

then again selected HP and scrolled way down the list to HP Laserjet III Series and selected it.

This driver only allows 300dpi resolution, but it is better then printer not working at all.

Comment: I found this "fix" before asking here. The problem is there is no "HP Laserjet III" (or II) drivers that I can see in my list.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the HP LaserJet III drivers above, you must click on "Windows Update" and it will give you more printers.